# bash(シェル)からmysqlのSELECTを行いJSONで出力する方法

Tags: mysql, bash, jq

bashでmysqlのSELECTを行いJSONで出力する方法を知りたいと思っています。

具体的には、

```
echo "SELECT * from testtable;" | mysql --defaults-extra-file=./my.conf testdb
```

の結果をJSONで出力して、jqコマンドで値を取り扱いたいと考えています。

mysqlのバージョンは、

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: MySQL のバージョンはいくつでしょうか？ MySQL 5.7 から `JSON_OBJECT` などの関数が導入されています。

Answer (score 1):

`pip install csvkit` を実行して、 csvjson コマンドをインストールします。その後に、

```
mysql -B -e "select * from some_table" some_db | csvjson -d $'\t'
```

を実行すると、やりたいことが実現できると思います。

一つだけうまくいかない場合があり、テーブルの中にタブ文字が含まれる場合は、もう少し考える必要があります。